# Multiple application on network with same SQL database

Tags: sql

I will have multiple computers on the same network with the same C# application running, connecting to a SQL database.

I am wondering if I need to use the service broker to ensure that if I update record A in table B on Machine 1, the change is pushed to Machine 2. I have seen applications that need to use messaging servers to accomplish this before but I was wondering why this is necessary, surely if they connect to the same database, any changes from one machine will be reflected on the other?

Thanks :)

Comment: If you have one database, and several connections, the updates will be there for everybody.

Comment: Which "SQL database" system are you talking about? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird? SQL is just a query language not a DBMS product.

Comment: My apologies, I should have made that clear, SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly about consistency and latency.

If your applications always perform atomic operations on the database, and they always read whatever they need with no caching, everything will be consistent.

In practice, this is seldom the case. There's plenty of hidden opportunities for caching, like when you have an edit form - it has the values the entity had before you started the edit process, but what if someone modified those in the mean time? You'd just rewrite their changes with your data.

Solving this is a bunch of architectural decisions. Different scenarios require different approaches.

Once data is committed in the database, everyone reading it will see the same thing - but only if they actually get around to reading it, and the two reads aren't separated by another commit.

Update notifications are mostly concerned with invalidating caches, and perhaps some push-style processing (e.g. IM client might show you a popup saying you got  a new message). However, SQL Server notifications are not reliable - there is no guarantee that you'll get the notification, and even less so that you'll get it in time. This means that to ensure consistency, you must not depend on the cached data, and you have to force an invalidation once in  a while *anyway*, even if you didn't get a change notification.

Remember, even if you're actually using a database that's close enough to ACID, it's usually not the default setting (for performance and availability, mostly). You need to understand what kind of guarantees you're getting, and how to write code to handle this. Even the most perfect ACID database isn't going to help your consistency if your application introduces those inconsistencies :)